# How to ignore typescript or idm errors?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, error-handling

I have an angular project, In the project, I have a service it returns an object, And In the app component, I'm using that object.

```
theobject.profileImg
```

Everything works properly, But Idm shows this err. " Property 'profileImg' does not exist on type 'object'. "

I'm using vsCode

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is always better to prepare types properly and avoid situations like you have.

for example:

```
export interface SomeInterface{
  public profileImg: any;
}

const anotherVar: SomeInterface = theobject;
anotherVar.profileImg; // this will be fine
```

Another option is use `any` type:

```
(company as any).profileImg
```

Or

```
theobject['profileImg']
```

Also, if you just want to skip it in one place use `@ts-ignore`

```
// @ts-ignore: some description
theobject.profileImg
```

Or disable linting at all.

Answer (score 1):

In template use like:

```
theobject?.profileImg
```

or

```
theobject['profileImg']
```

but generally better add model to your object, like:

```
theobject: IObject;
```

and

```
interface IObject {
 profileImg: string;
 id: number;
 //and more
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using type `Object` shows this kind of error. The best practice is to create your own interface (which will have the attribute `profileImg`) to enable autocompletion. If you choose not to do so, use type `any` instead